# Frações de 15 minutos no registro do tempo em PHP

Tags: php, data, php-7

Tenho um sistema de cobrança por horas o qual estou tentando realizar cobranças por frações de 15 min. Ele pega a diferença do horário de entrada e saída e adiciona o restante de tempo, exemplo:

- Entrada 09:00 - Saída 09:11
- Tempo real: 00:11 - Tempo de cobrança: 00:15.

E assim sucessivamente de 15 em 15.

Montei um código que funciona até 60 minutos, no entanto, minha dúvida reside em depois que passa deste tempo. Ele não adiciona as frações, e sim os minutos normais.

Existe alguma forma dele reconhecer que, após 01:00:01 deve-se adicionar a fração de 15 sucessivamente? Abaixo segue o código:

```
<?php 
$horaInicial = $_POST['inicio'];
$horaFinal = $_POST['final'];
$fator15 = 900;
$fator30 = 1800;
$fator45 = 2700;
$fator60 = 3600;
$horaMais = 3600;


$horaInicial = strtotime($horaInicial);
$horaFinal = strtotime($horaFinal);

$totalSegundos = ($horaFinal - $horaInicial);



switch($totalSegundos){
    case ($totalSegundos < $fator15):
        while($totalSegundos < $fator15){
            $totalSegundos++;
        }
        break;

    case ($totalSegundos > $fator15 && $totalSegundos < $fator30):
        while($totalSegundos < $fator30){
            $totalSegundos++;
        }
        break;

    case ($totalSegundos > $fator30 && $totalSegundos < $fator45):
        while($totalSegundos < $fator45){
            $totalSegundos++;
        }
        break;

    case ($totalSegundos > $fator45 && $totalSegundos < $fator60):
        while($totalSegundos < $fator60){
            $totalSegundos++;
        }
        break;
    case($totalSegundos > $fator60):
        while($totalSegundos < $fator15){
            $totalSegundos++;
        }

}



$resultado = gmdate("H:i", $totalSegundos);

echo "Total: ".$resultado;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está trabalhando com a diferença em minutos, pode ignorar os segundos, então a primeira coisa é dividir a diferença por 60:

```
$totalMinutos = ($horaFinal - $horaInicial) / 60;
```

Em seguida basta ver quantos intervalos de 15 minutos existem neste total (e usando [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) para arredondar para cima):

```
$intervalosDe15 = ceil($totalMinutos / 15);
```

Com isso você obtém a quantidade de intervalos de 15 minutos. Por exemplo, se a hora inicial for 09:00 e a hora final for 10:11, o resultado é 5.

Para obter o total de minutos equivalente, basta multiplicar por 15:

```
$intervaloMinutos = $intervalosDe15 * 15;
```

---

E agora chegamos no ponto em que você imprime o resultado. Você está usando [`gmdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), que imprime uma data em determinado formato. Mas a informação que você tem (o intervalo em minutos) não é uma data. Existem dois conceitos diferentes aqui:

- uma **data/hora** representa um ponto específico na linha do tempo: uma data é um ponto do calendário (ex: dia 2 do mês de abril de 2019) e um horário representa um ponto específico do dia (ex: duas e meia da tarde)
- uma **duração** representa uma quantidade de tempo, sem nenhuma relação direta com calendários. Ex: a duração do filme é de duas horas (eu não disse que horas ele começa, nem se de fato vai começar, é apenas **a quantidade de tempo**, sem nenhuma relação com datas ou horários)

Ambos podem usar as mesmas palavras (dias, horas, minutos, etc), mas são conceitos diferentes.

`gmdate` trabalha com datas, mas o que você tem (`$intervaloMinutos`) é uma duração. E para trabalhar com durações, você deve usar um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$intervaloMinutos = $intervalosDe15 * 15;
$horas = floor($intervaloMinutos / 60);
$minutos = $intervaloMinutos % 60;
$interval = new DateInterval("PT{$horas}H{$minutos}M");
echo $interval->format('%H:%I'); // hh:mm
```

Primeiro eu transformo os intervalos de 15 minutos no total de minutos. Depois eu pego a quantidade de horas e minutos e crio o `DateInterval`.

O construtor de `DateInterval` precisa receber os valores no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). No caso, `PTxHyM` representa uma duração de x horas e y minutos. Em seguida, eu uso o método [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) para formatar o `DateInterval`.

Usando a hora inicial 09:00 e a hora final 10:11, `$intervalosDe15` será igual a 5, então `$intervaloMinutos` será 75 (ou seja, a duração total é de 75 minutos).

Em seguida, `$horas` será 1 e `minutos` será 15, e ao formatar o `DateInterval`, o resultado será `01:15`.

Comment: Não é um resposta é uma verdadeira aula. Estou muito agradecido pela ajuda.Irei implementar no código e posto o resultado. Espero um dia chegar ao seu nível!